# Not Able to Fetch Data from server using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

Not any errors are showing but data are not fetching form server.

my Main Activity

```
public class RetroMain extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://www.myeducationhunt.com/api/v1/colleges";

    //Strings to bind with intent will be used to send data to other activity
    public static final String KEY_BOOK_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_BOOK_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_BOOK_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_BOOK_DISTRICT = "district";
    private ListView listView;

    //List of type books this list will store type Book which is our data model
    private List<Book> books;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retro_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewBooks);
        getBooks();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }


    private void getBooks() {
        //While the app fetched data we are displaying a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);

        //Creating a rest adapter
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ROOT_URL).build();

        //Creating an object of our api interface
        BooksAPI api = adapter.create(BooksAPI.class);

        //Defining the method
        api.getBooks(new Callback<List<Book>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Book> list, Response response) {
                //Dismissing the loading progressbar
                loading.dismiss();

                //Storing the data in our list
                books = list;

                //Calling a method to show the list
                showList();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                //you can handle the errors here
            }
        });
    }

    //Our method to show list
    private void showList() {
        //String array to store all the book names
        String[] items = new String[books.size()];

        //Traversing through the whole list to get all the names
        for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
            //Storing names to string array
            items[i] = books.get(i).getName();
        }

        //Creating an array adapter for list view
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list, items);

        //Setting adapter to listview
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

//Creating an intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowBookDetails.class);

        //Getting the requested book from the list
        Book book = books.get(position);

        //Adding book details to intent
        intent.putExtra(KEY_BOOK_ID, book.getId());
        intent.putExtra(KEY_BOOK_NAME, book.getName());
        intent.putExtra(KEY_BOOK_ADDRESS, book.getAddress());
        intent.putExtra(KEY_BOOK_DISTRICT, book.getDistrict());

        //Starting another activity to show book details
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

my getter and setters

```
public class Book {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String district;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

my API Interface

```
public interface BooksAPI {

    @GET("/api/v1/colleges")
    public void getBooks(Callback<List<Book>> response);
}
```

ShowBookDetails class

```
public class ShowBookDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Defining views
    private TextView id;
    private TextView name;
    private TextView address;
    private TextView district;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_book_details);

        //Initializing Views
        id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
        district = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.district);

        //Getting intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //Displaying values by fetching from intent
        id.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra(RetroMain.KEY_BOOK_ID, 0)));
        name.setText(intent.getStringExtra(RetroMain.KEY_BOOK_NAME));
        address.setText(intent.getStringExtra(RetroMain.KEY_BOOK_ADDRESS));
        district.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra(RetroMain.KEY_BOOK_DISTRICT, 0)));
    }
}
```

my main xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Mystic.activity.RetroMain">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewBooks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my activity_show_book_detail

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/district"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

simple_list

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp">

</TextView>
```

i am not able to fetch data from server?

Comment: What version of retrofit are you using?

Comment: Your base url should: `http://www.myeducationhunt.com`. And check logs the url is correct or not

Comment: i am using 1.9.0 retrofit

Comment: @ Charitha i have changed to http://www.myeducationhunt.com but not thing happens

Comment: @seon What is logs says?

Comment: to where i have to add stack Trace for checking url i am confused?@charitha

Comment: Where did u create the retrofit instance???

Comment: nice error handling: `public void failure(RetrofitError error) {}`

Comment: U will never get the output if u do like this with retrofit,i cannot see a retrofit instance anywhere??

Comment: @cha ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.animationbook.test/lib

Comment: This is a wrong code..!!!!

Comment: @Roy i used https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/ this url .please see this url

Comment: First create a retrofit instance ,  mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ROOT_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();, Then create an api object , mRestApis = mRetrofit.create(BooksApi.class);

Comment: @Roy can you please provide any helpful link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134140/discussion-between-seon-and-roy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding full url here `"public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://www.myeducationhunt.com/api/v1/colleges";"` 
which is not correct you just needs to add the base url here.
Modify this url to

```
public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://www.myeducationhunt.com/";
```

Also in your interface remove the initial "/"
This  `@GET("/api/v1/colleges")` to  this ... `@GET("api/v1/colleges")`

**Edit1:**
Your problem with oncreate method.. remove your oncreate method with the following code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewBooks);
        getBooks();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/ i have followed this tutorial

Comment: @seon Okey that tutorial is fine..  Check the Root_url in that tutorial they are just adding the domain. You are adding full url at the place of root_url

Comment: i made changes nothing Happens.sir

Comment: Maybe you are getting error So just add log inside of failure method like System.out.println(error.getMessage()); and tell me what is the error? Also pls update your question with your changes..  It will helps to identify the issue..

Comment: if i do this,
public static final String ROOT_URL = "api/v1/colleges";
how can it find out the actual url.sir

Comment: @seon really sorry to waste your time. Check my answer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134141/discussion-between-seon-and-amsheer).

Comment: interface should be @GET("/api/v1/colleges") not @GET("api/v1/colleges") .edit your answer @Amsheer

Comment: I think that is not needed. Maybe in 1.9 Retrofit it is needed. But if you go to Retrofit 2.1 Base url must end with "/". And starts with "/". Check both combination which one suits you keep that one.